# The inequality $\max(x,y) \lt 4$ means $x \gt 4$ or $y \gt 4$

Tags: inequality

Can anybody help me why The inequality $\max(x,y) \lt 4$ means $x \gt 4$ or $y \gt 4$. Please use graphs for your explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Simply put, it does *not* mean that, as written. Rather, $\max(x,y)<4$ means that $x<4$ and $y<4.$ This is because $x\le\max(x,y)<4$ and $y\le\max(x,y)<4$.

I suppose you intended your initial inequality to be $\max(x,y)>4,$ instead, in which case, it *is* true. But why? Well, let's suppose $x\le 4$ and $y\le 4.$ If $x\le y,$ then $\max(x,y)=y\le 4,$ and otherwise, $\max(x,y)=x\le 4,$ so $\max(x,y)\le 4$ in either case. Hence, by [contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrapositive), $\max(x,y)>4$ implies that $x>4$ or $y>4.$

If you want a graph of the inequality plot, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%28x%2Cy%29%3E4).

Comment: Just to add a little clarity, max(x,y) is a symbol for the maximum value of x and y. It could be the case that x=1, y=3, and in such a case, max(x,y) = 3.